# Linux - How to view the log file from the program script?

Tags: linux

how to view the log file from the script? I tried less / logfile but not working

[man script here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you must either specify the logfile you want the output directed to such as:

~]# script [OPTIONS] filename

if no filename is specified when you first launch the script command, then it defaults to saving into filename "typescript" -- so check in whatever directory you first launched the command from.

doing a cat typescript or cat filename should bring up the file's contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you started script using `script logfile`, then, a `less logfile` should work.